# How does setParameterList in hibernate work?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am having some problem with the setParameterList api of hibernate.

I am trying to pass in a Collection to a SQLQuery and doing an "in" clause search.The records exists in the DB and doing a raw query, I am able to retrieve them or if I just replace them in the same Hibernate SQL like `emp.emp_name in ('Joe','John')`, I am able to get the desired result set. I am confused as to why would Hibernate fail to replace the Collection in place of the named parameter. Here is the code :

```
session.createSQLQuery("select emp_id as id from emp where emp.emp_name in (:empNames)")
       .addScalar("id",Hibernate.INTEGER)
       .setParameterList("empNames",new String[]{"Joe","John"})
       .list()
```

I have looked at the [Hibernate Documentation for setParameterList](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29) but I am not able to reason out this particular behavior.

Comment: You might want to provide more information on the error (e.g. stacktrace etc.) to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am afraid there is no exception per se thrown by Hibernate for this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is precisely *because* you're using `createSQLQuery`. The single parameter here needs to be changed into multiple parameters in the real SQL, but by using a "raw" query you're telling Hibernate not to mess with the SQL.

Can you use a "normal" Hibernate query instead?

Comment: Thanks Jon, the problem got resolved once I switched over to using HQL instead of the native SQL.

Comment: Just thought I'd throw in that for me exactly such a query is working fine, and I suspect the real problem with your query is that you're mixing hibernate/sql.  So in actuality all you would have to get rid of is the .addScalar("id",Hibernate.INTEGER) and turn it into a setParameter(id, theId), because the actual list portion is fine and is working great for me throughout my project.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the parenthesis around the parameter name :

```
session.createSQLQuery("select emp_id as id from emp where emp.emp_name in :empNames ")
   .addScalar("id",Hibernate.INTEGER)
   .setParameterList("empNames",new String[]{"Joe","John"})
   .list()
```

Comment: Please add a little more explanation

Comment: Don't write "in (:empNames)" but "in :empNames" when "empNames" is a parameterlist for a SQLQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to use (N)Hibernate's parameter lists. Query plans in cache are not used when the number of elements in parameter list is different. So it means your query is often hard parsed and compiled. Queries are slower, database load is higher and plan cache is full of plans generated for the same query.